# When running a wireless charging circuit, my power supply whines and the transistor gets super hot even though everything works, is anything wrong?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, wireless, led-driver, overheat

I created a wireless LED power circuit to drive adafruit wireless LEDs.The circuit works great, LEDs are fully lit but my desktop power supply lets out an awful whine whenever its running (it normally doesn't for other circuits) and the BD139 transistor gets extremely hot. I am wondering if this is expected behavior or an error in the circuit. I attached an image of the circuit for reference.

Thanks for any ideas!

[image: schematic]

Notes:

- the coil is basic insulated solid core wire that you would use for a breadboard, ~2cm radius, 6 turns
- its running 2.74v drawing 0.217a

Comment: right now your circuit is basically sending the same high-frequency wave back to the power supply, as it changes its power consumption however thousands of times per second, causing components in the power supply to vibrate. Adding a bypass capacitor will make it stop doing that. I bet it will solve the whine and it might increase the power level causing Q3 to go pop.

Comment: also look up a "flyback diode" and its purpose; if the coil is good, then Q3 absorbs all the energy stored in the coil when it turns off (if the coil is bad then Q3 just absorbs energy from the power supply as a short circuit)